# Problem to send data on Express.js / MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, mongoose, postman

i get error about `Body-Parser` when i post data with Postman on `localhost:3000/send-data`
, i thought it can get fixed with express.json() but it didn't, also what is the simplest way to post data to mongoDB with React-native?

here are my codes:

app.js :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
require("./ads")
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
const Ads = mongoose.model("ads")
const mongoURI = *
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

mongoose.connection.on("connected",() => {
    console.log("connected to server")
})
mongoose.connection.on("error",(err) => {
    console.log("error",error)
})
app.post('/send-data',(req,res) => {
    const ads = new Ads({
    name : req.body.name,
    title : req.body.title,
    title2 : req.body.title2,
    })
    ads.save()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        res.send("seccsudss")
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send("welcome to nodejs")
})

app.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

and error i get is :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 185
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/home/kian/project/project/project/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /home/kian/project/project/project/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/kian/project/project/project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/kian/project/project/project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/kian/project/project/project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Comment: Can you add your postman request?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass **string as json keys**

```
{
   "name" : req.body.name,
   "title" : req.body.title,
   "title2" : req.body.title2 
}
```